# Find probability of students to cheat with Bernoulli model

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, stan

I have been trying to solve this for a long time now, but I still can't figure it out.

Background of the problem:
I have data on two exams. There were suspicions that many people cheated on the first exam, and therefore a second exam was conducted. 400 students took both exams and the maximum score on both exams is 200.

[image]

The goal is to generate a posterior distribution of the probability that a student has cheated or not.

My idea was to first make a new variable, with the difference in score of the two exams (density of the difference is shown below), and then apply a Bernoulli model where success means it's a cheater. The problem I have is that I don't know the input for my Bernoulli random variable (= I don't have the information about who cheated and who didn't cheat, which to my understanding would be my "y" variable in a Bernoulli distribution). Therefore, I'm not sure how to proceed or if I can even use a Bernoulli model?

So I tried to make a new variable consisting only of zeros (variable n) to have non-success as a starting point, which would allow me to get the probability that each student did not cheat, but it didn't work.

[image: Difference in score between the two exams]

Here are more details to what I have already done.

I have to write the model in .stan code format.

```
data{
  int  Diff[400];
  int n[400];
}
parameters{
  ordered [2] a0;
  real a[400];
  real <lower=0> sigma_1;
  real <lower=0> sigma_2;
  real <lower=0, upper=1> theta;
}
model{
  vector[400] p;
  theta ~ beta(2, 2);
  a0 ~ normal (0 ,10);
  sigma_1 ~ cauchy (0 ,1);
  sigma_2 ~ cauchy (0 ,1);
  for(i in 1:400){
    target += log_sum_exp(bernoulli_lpmf (1| theta) + normal_lpdf(a[i]| a0[1],sigma_1),
                          bernoulli_lpmf (0| theta) + normal_lpdf(a[i]| a0[2], sigma_2));
  }
  for(i in 1:400)
    p[i] = a[i];
  n ~ binomial_logit(1, p);
}
```

Diff is the difference in score of Exam1 and Exam2.
n[400], is a vector of length 400, where each entry is 0.
a0 are the mu's for the mixture model (=the two peaks in Fig.2).
a are the intercepts of each individual, which is related to the probability.
In the last line, n ~ binomial_logit(1, p), I hoped to predict the probability that a student did NOT cheat, as n only consists of zeros. And therefore the resulting p would be not to cheat.

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.